# PageIterator as generic extension method on GetAsync()

Tags: c#, type-inference, microsoft-graph-sdks

The graph API returns for several kind of request (User, Groups, etc.) a *page*. This element contains the first bunch of elements and the `NextPageRequest` property that can be used to make the next `GetAsync()` call.

To make these things a little bit easier, also the `PageIterator<T>` is available to get as much elements as needed. Before this we had a bunch of helper extension methods, that lacks this generic approach and are implemented for each kind of type seperately more or less like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<DirectoryObject>> GetAll(this Task<IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage> collectionTask)
{
    // Argument checks, error handling and parameter for max item count omitted for better readability
    var collectionPage = await collectionTask;

    var start = (IEnumerable<DirectoryObject>)(collectionPage);

    while (collectionPage.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        collectionPage = await collectionPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        start = start.Concat(collectionPage);
    }

    return start;
}
```

These kind of extension methods allowed to write something like this:

```
var currentGroupMembers = await serviceClient.Groups[azureGroup.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync().GetAll();
```

Due to the fact, that each kind of type returns its own type of `...Collection...Page` we had to write the same method and just replacing the given types.

Now `PageIterator<T>` comes into play and we tried to write a generic function that works on all `Task<ICollectionPage<TItem>>`. While it is quite easy to write such a function:

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyList<TItem>> GetAllWithPageIterator<TItem>(this Task<ICollectionPage<TItem>> pageTask, IBaseClient baseClient)
{
    // Argument checks, error handling and parameter for max item count omitted for better readability
    var page = await pageTask;
    var allElements = new List<TItem>();

    var iterator = PageIterator<TItem>.CreatePageIterator(baseClient, page, item =>
    {
        allElements.Add(item);
        return true;
    });

    await iterator.IterateAsync();
    return allElements;
}
```

You can simply not use it:

```
// Extension method explicitly called to better show error message.
var task = serviceClient.Groups[azureGroup.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();
await IGraphServiceCollectionPageExtensions.GetAllWithPageIterator<DirectoryObject>(task, serviceClient);

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Graph.IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Graph.ICollectionPage<Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject>>'
```

But `IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage` implements `Microsoft.Graph.ICollectionPage<Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject>`, but I think the reason is the outer type `Task<T>` avoids the usage as generic extension. If you rewrite the above extension method to use only the `ICollectionPage<T>` everything works as expected. But that would break up the extension method to be always used as a two liner:

```
var firstPage = await serviceClient.Groups[azureGroup.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();
var allItems = firstPage.GetAllWithPageIterator(firstPage, serviceClient);
```

While this works, it just looks bad to me (also if you would write `(await serviceClient...GetAsync()).GetAll...`). It just looks like not being really matching and a real fluent solution like `GetAsync().GetAll()` with generic constraints would be great.